# SAS Same logical applied to a list of variables?

Tags: sas, range

I'm trying to apply the same logical on all the variables and create a new variable based on the logical:

```
DATA want;
    SET have;
    IF "range" = 25 THEN "new range" = 1
        ELSE "new range" = 0;
RUN;
```

If it's easier I can also just change the variables themselves as opposed to creating new variables from the logical statement.

As an example, I want any value within the variables of 25 to be 1, and everything else to be 0:

HAVE:

```
var_100     var_101     var_102
30          25          20
45          100         25
25          25          10
```

WANT:

```
var_100     var_101     var_102
0          1            0
0          0            1
1          1            0
```

So I have about 100 variables with all the same prefix and increasing suffices. Instead of writing 100 logicals. I am trying to write one that will apply to every variable in that range of var_1 to var_100.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want? Could you show some actual values for a couple of variables and few observations and what derived variables you want to create.

Comment: See the example here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/ If you still have issues, post your code and explain your issues. Note that your question does not meet the SO rules because you haven't really shown an attempt. Your code above isn't valid.

Comment: @Reeza I have to disagree, I think that attempt is fine for a beginner level programmer.  It shows clearly what the programmer is attempting to do.

Comment: @Joe we can disagree then :) If you ask how to expand something to all variables, your sample should at least work for the one you claim you want to do for all variables. This won't since it doesn't refer to variables properly.

Comment: @Reeza The question is asking how to [do this thing], and shows pseudocode to [do this thing], the user just doesn't know how to do it.  That's way more than we get from 90% of questions here... and definitely meets the minimum standards expected.  The expectation isn't that questions already know techniques they're asking about after all; the point of that expectation is to avoid help vampires who just ask how to do their work.  When it's a tightly tailored question like this ("how do I apply same logic to list of variables") it's entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lots* of ways you can do this, mostly based on what exactly you're doing to what.

Arrays are the simplest:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array vars[25] var1-var25;
  array newvars[25] n_var1 - n_var25;
  do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
    if vars[_i] = 25 then newvars[_i] = 1;
    else newvars[_i] = 0;
  end;
run;
```

Of course you need some reasonable way to specify those variable lists (`var1-var25` and `n_var1 - n_var25`); if they're not just sequential, you'll either have to write them all out, or use the macro language to do that.

Another way is to write a macro to do what you want.

```
%macro recode(invar=, outvar=, inval=, outval=, otherval=);
  if &invar. = &inval. then &outvar. = &outval.;
  else &outvar. = &otherval.;
%mend recode;

data want;
  set have;
  %recode(invar=var1, outvar=n_Var1, inval=25, outval=1, otherval=0);
  .. 25 of these ..
run;
```

You can then generate these macro calls with code; search on "sas data driven programming" either here or on a search engine for examples.

The latter is better if that 25 -> 1 changes by the variable.  The former is better if it doesn't and the variables are easily "listable" (like var1-var25).  If they're not listable, but the 25->1 is fixed, either one works about the same in my opinion.

And of course instead of using newvars you can just recode var[_i] = 1 or whatever if that's easier.

---

As an aside, there are also simpler ways of coding variables to 1/0 flags if that's what you're doing using procs.  I think PROC SCORE is one common way, but probably worth a separate question if you want to go this route.